# RealmSwift travis build time

Tags: swift, realm, travis-ci

I'm using travis ci to build a swift project, but my build is rather slow.

the pod file:

```
platform :ios, '9.3'
use_frameworks!

target 'FlightAssistant' do
  pod 'RealmSwift'
end
```

and my travis.ml with cocoa pods cache enabled.

```
language: objective-c
osx_image: xcode7.3
cache: cocoapods

script:
  - xcodebuild -workspace App.xcworkspace/   -scheme AppTests -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=9.3' test
```

considerable time in the build is spent recompiling the entire realm database. total build time is 8mins right now. Is there anyway to speed up this process further?

Comment: CocoaPods integrates library as source code. So rebuilding entire libraries every tests. The only way to solve that, you should use pre-built binary instead CocoaPods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to change cache settings like the following:

```
language: objective-c
osx_image: xcode7.2
cache:
  directories:    
    - Pods    
    - $HOME/.cocoapods    
    - $HOME/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try caching the mtimes of your source files, as well as the intermediate file directory. See the [mtime_cache](https://github.com/iboB/mtime_cache) tool. It's designed primarily for C/C++ but I think your problem is very similar and it will help as well.